# Stanford CoreNLP Statistical Coref System NullPointerException

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to apply the statistical coreference system to process a text file with the following command

```
java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,cleanxml,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,coref -file input.txt
```

This throws the following error message:

```
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokenizerAnnotator - TokenizerAnnotator: No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator cleanxml
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [0.9 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator lemma
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ner
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.8 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [0.8 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.0 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator parse
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar - Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ...
done [0.4 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator coref

Processing file /home/xilin/Toolkits/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09/input.txt ... writing to /home/xilin/Toolkits/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09/input.txt.out
Annotating file /home/xilin/Toolkits/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09/input.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error annotating document with coref
at edu.stanford.nlp.scoref.StatisticalCorefSystem.annotate(StatisticalCorefSystem.java:86)
at edu.stanford.nlp.scoref.StatisticalCorefSystem.annotate(StatisticalCorefSystem.java:63)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.CorefAnnotator.annotate(CorefAnnotator.java:97)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotationPipeline.annotate(AnnotationPipeline.java:72)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.annotate(StanfordCoreNLP.java:534)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.annotate(StanfordCoreNLP.java:544)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.processFiles(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1098)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.processFiles(StanfordCoreNLP.java:877)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.run(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1187)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.main(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1257)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.Preprocessor.assignMentionIDs(Preprocessor.java:170)
at edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.Preprocessor.initializeMentions(Preprocessor.java:153)
at edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.Preprocessor.preprocess(Preprocessor.java:64)
at edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.CorefDocMaker.makeDocument(CorefDocMaker.java:194)
at edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.CorefDocMaker.makeDocument(CorefDocMaker.java:154)
at edu.stanford.nlp.scoref.StatisticalCorefSystem.annotate(StatisticalCorefSystem.java:68)
... 9 more
```

If I changed the option "coref" in the above command to "dcoref", the deterministic coreference system runs smoothly. Others have pointed out that this is a [BUG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34902540/stanford-corenlp-pipeline-coref-parsing-some-short-strings-with-few-mentions) in 3.6.0 distribution. I am using the [github repository](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP), and I'm getting the latest version. However the bug seems to exist still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the `mention` annotator before `coref`. The fact that this appears as a null pointer exception is indeed a bug though. Which Git revision are you using? We've recently changed the way requirements are handled, and this may be a remnant bug from that.

Comment: Indeed. In particular, this is a problem in the current post-v3.6.0 current code. If you run this command using the v3.6.0 jar, you do correctly get: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: annotator "coref" requires annotator "mention"`.

Comment: The program is able to run through if I add the mention annotator before coref. I git-pulled and recompiled the jar yesterday. Hence I suppose this is a hidden bug in the repo.

Comment: The bug's been fixed!